# XML name space prefix 'json' declaration is missing for FOR XML column name 'Value/@json:ValueType'

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, xml, xml-namespaces

I am working on a project where the stored procedure I am writing is producing XML format output. I want to add a namespace to the 'Main' node and add JSON ValueType to the sub nodes. Below is my code:

```
--- Fake tables in stored procedure
create table #Cdetails(cid int, cidtype varchar(5), name varchar(5), age int)

insert into #Cdetails
values (1001, 'N', 'John', 12), (1002, 'U', 'Rick', 19),
       (1003, 'N', 'Diane', 25), (1004, 'N', 'Kippy', 26)

--Output of stored procedure 

create table #final(cid int, cidtype varchar(5), xml_data xml)

insert into #final
    select
        cid = c1.cid,
        cidtype = c1.cidtype,
        case 
           when c1.cidtype = 'N' 
              then (select 
                        'Value/@json:ValueType'='Number',
                        ID = cd1.cid,
                        details = (select  
                                       cd1.name, cd1.age
                                   for xml path(''), type)
                    from  
                        #Cdetails cd1
                    where 
                        cd1.cid = c1.cid
                    for xml path('Main'))
           when c1.cidtype = 'N' 
              then (select 
                        ID = cd1.cid,
                        details = 'Null'            
                    from 
                        #Cdetails cd1
                    where 
                        cd1.cid = c1.cid
                    for xml path('Main')) 
        end as 'xml_data'
    from 
        #Cdetails c1 

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.integround.com/json' as json)  
SELECT * 
FROM #final 
WHERE xml_data IS NOT NULL
FOR XML PATH('Main')

drop table #Cdetails, #final
```

In this procedure, the XML is generated based on CIDType condition. So my current output is:

[image]

I want to add the namespace to the 'Main' node and add the JSON property to sub nodes.

Error

> XML name space prefix 'json' declaration is missing for FOR XML column name 'Value/@json:ValueType'.

Desired output:

[image]

Any help?!

Answer (score 0):

Can the [XML Construction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xml-construction-xquery?view=sql-server-2017) help you?

```
DECLARE @cdetails table(
  cid INT, cidtype VARCHAR(5), name VARCHAR(5), age INT
);

INSERT INTO @cdetails VALUES
  (1001, 'N', 'John', 22), (1002, 'U', 'Rick', 21),
  (1003, 'N', 'Diane', 25), (1004, 'N', 'Kippy', 26);

SELECT
  cid, cidtype,
  CAST('' AS XML).query('
<Main xmlns:json="http://www.samplenamespace.com/json">
  <ID json:ValueType="Number">{sql:column("cid")}</ID>
  {
    if( sql:column("cidtype")="N" ) then
      <details>
        <name>{sql:column("name")}</name>
        <age>{sql:column("age")}</age>
      </details>
    else <details>Null</details>
  }
</Main>
  ')
FROM @cdetails;
```